# Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread

Tags: web-services, spring, session, jcr

I have two Spring applications: client and server. On server application are services, on client app is view logic. Both apps should communicate through web-services, but this did not work because of error

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsSoapFaultException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.jcrSession': Scope 'session' is
>   not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy
>   for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request
>   found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
>   web request, or processing a request outside of the originally
>   receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
>   and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside
>   of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.

On server app i'm using JCR Session (session scoped bean)

```
<bean name="jcrSession" factory-bean="sessionFactory" factory-method="login" scope="session" destroy-method="logout" >
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

in web.xml of server app I have

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When I access WSDL files produced by server app in browser, everything is OK. When I use server app services locally (e.g. in controller on server app) everything is also OK. So why this error occurs, when I try to access services through web-services from remote app?

**Update1**
`jcrSession` is crated by `SessionFactory` class. Then this `jcrSession` is autowired to DAO objects using springs `@Autowired`.

```
Example of simplified `JcrSessionFactory`:
public class JcrSessionFactory {

    private Repository repository;
    private Credentials credentials;
    private Session session;

    public Session login() {
        session = repository.login(credentials);
        return session;
    }

    public void logout() {
        session.logout();
    }
}
```

Also, same error occured when I tried to autowire service in same app and use it in method annotated by `@PostConstruct` or in implementation of `InitializingBean` in method `afterPropertiesSet()`

Comment: What is referring to `jcrSession`?